# Combine two JSON objects in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have two JSON rows in a PostgreSQL 9.4 table:

```
      the_column      
----------------------
 {"evens": [2, 4, 6]}
 {"odds": [1, 3, 5]}
```

I want to combine all of the rows into one JSON object. (It should work for any number of rows.)

Desired output:

`{"evens": [2, 4, 6], "odds": [1, 3, 5]}`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use [**`json_agg()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE) to build an array of objects:

```
SELECT json_agg(the_column) AS result
FROM   tbl;
```

Or [**`json_each()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) in a `LATERAL` join and [**`json_object_agg()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE) to build an object with unnested key/value pairs (your desired output):

```
SELECT json_object_agg(key, value) AS the_column
FROM   tbl, json_each(the_column);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/flBusU9I)

Comment: (For clarity, note that in his answer, `data` is a json column in the table `tbl`. - If it's a jsonb column, remember to use `jsonb_each`.)

Answer (score 20):

FYI, if someone's using jsonb in >= 9.5 and they only care about top-level elements being merged without duplicate keys, then it's as easy as using the || operator:

```
select '{"evens": [2, 4, 6]}'::jsonb || '{"odds": [1, 3, 5]}'::jsonb;
            ?column?                 
-----------------------------------------
{"odds": [1, 3, 5], "evens": [2, 4, 6]}
(1 row)
```

Comment: This is combining columns, not rows.