# Postgres SQL query, that will group fields in nested JSON objects

Tags: postgresql, subquery

I need a SQL query in Postgres that produce a JSON with grouped/inherited data,
see example below.

having a table "issues" with following example data:

```
+--------------------------------------+-------+------------+-----------------------+
|              product_id              | level |  typology  |        comment        |
+--------------------------------------+-------+------------+-----------------------+
| e1227f18-0c1f-4ebb-8cbf-a09c74ba14f5 |     1 | electronic | LED broken            |
| e1227f18-0c1f-4ebb-8cbf-a09c74ba14f5 |     1 | mechanical | missing gear          |
| e1227f18-0c1f-4ebb-8cbf-a09c74ba14f5 |     1 | mechanical | cover damaged         |
| e1227f18-0c1f-4ebb-8cbf-a09c74ba14f5 |     2 | electric   | switch wrong color    |
| e1227f18-0c1f-4ebb-8cbf-a09c74ba14f5 |     2 | mechanical | missing o-ring        |
| e1227f18-0c1f-4ebb-8cbf-a09c74ba14f5 |     2 | electric   | plug wrong type       |
| 3567ae01-c7b3-4cd7-9e4f-85730aab89ee |     1 | mechanical | gear wrong dimensions |
+--------------------------------------+-------+------------+-----------------------+

product_id, typology and comment are string.
level is an integer.
```

I want to obtain this JSON:

```
{
  "e1227f18-0c1f-4ebb-8cbf-a09c74ba14f5": {
    "1": {
      "electronic": [ "LED broken" ],
      "mechanical": [ "missing gear", "cover damaged"]
    },
    "2": {
      "electronic": [ "switch wrong color", "plug wrong type" ],
      "mechanical": [ "missing o-ring" ]
    }
  },
  "3567ae01-c7b3-4cd7-9e4f-85730aab89ee": {
    "1": {
      "mechanical": [ "gear wrong dimensions"]
    }
  }
}
```

So I begun to wrote a query like this:

```
  SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(json_build_object(
    product_id, json_build_object(
      level, json_build_object(
        typology, comment
      )
    )
  ))) FROM issues
```

but I didn't realize ho to group/aggregate to obtain the wanted JSON

Answer (score 4):

[step-by-step demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=624fed649d71fc05258d0225f60c6e65)

```
SELECT 
    jsonb_object_agg(key, value)
FROM (
    SELECT
        jsonb_build_object(product_id, jsonb_object_agg(key, value)) as products
    FROM (
        SELECT
            product_id,
            jsonb_build_object(level, jsonb_object_agg(key, value)) AS level
        FROM (
            SELECT
                product_id,
                level,
                jsonb_build_object(typology, jsonb_agg(comment)) AS typology
            FROM
                issues
            GROUP BY product_id, level, typology
        ) s, 
        jsonb_each(typology)
    GROUP BY product_id, level
    ) s,
    jsonb_each(level)
    GROUP BY product_id
) s,
jsonb_each(products)
```

1. `jsonb_agg()` aggregates some values into one JSON array. This has been done with the `comments`.
2. After that there is a more complicated step. To aggregate two different JSON objects into one object, you need to do this:

[simplified demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=811d9b79e457996eee127e4d3ec43f7e)

First you need to expand the elements into a `key` and a `value` column using `jsonb_each()`. Now you are able to aggregate these two columns using the aggregate function `jsonb_object_agg()`. [See also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33403598/combine-two-json-objects-in-postgresql)

This is why the following steps look somewhat difficult. Every level of aggregation (`level` and `product_id`) need these steps because you want to merge the elements into single non-array JSON objects.

Because every single aggregation needs separate `GROUP BY` clauses, every step is done in its own subquery.