# Could not merge multiple Jsonb rows into a single row

Tags: json, postgresql, concatenation, jsonb, merging-data

Need to merge all the rows of my single jsonb column.

For example: my jsonb column has rows as the below one.

My input data is (2 rows):

```
{"room": ["101"],"equipments": ["thermometer"]}
{"room": ["101","102"], "equipments": ["stethescope"]}
```

upon running this query,

```
select (jsonb_each(jsonbcolumn)).* 
from table group by key, value
```

I get the following output,

```
    key         |       value
    equipments  |     ["stethescope"] 
    equipments  |     ["thermometer"]
    room        |     ["101","102"] 
    room        |     ["101"]
```

If I try to group by key add the values using jsonb_object_agg, jsonb eliminates the first value and retains only the second value.

```
{"room": ["101","102"],"equipments": ["stethescope"]}
```

If I try using json_object_agg, I get repetitive values

```
{ "room" : ["101"], "equipments" : ["thermometer"], "room" : ["101", "102"], "equipments" : ["stethescope"] }
```

My expected output is

```
{"room": ["101","102"], "equipments":["stethescope", "thermometer"]}
```

in a single row.

Tried out almost all solutions in the net. here are few links which i tried.

- [Merging Concatenating JSON(B) columns in query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30101603/merging-concatenating-jsonb-columns-in-query)
- [Combine two JSON objects in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33403598/combine-two-json-objects-in-postgresql)
- [How can I merge records inside two JSON arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34686141/how-can-i-merge-records-inside-two-json-arrays)

Answer (score 2):

The only solution I can think of is this:

```
select jsonb_build_object(
          'room', jsonb_agg(distinct r.room), 
          'equipments', jsonb_agg(distinct e.equipment) 
       )
from data d
  cross join jsonb_array_elements_text(d.jsonbcolumn -> 'room') as r(room)
  cross join jsonb_array_elements_text(d.jsonbcolumn -> 'equipments') as e(equipment)
```

but that's going to be extremely inefficient (but that's the price you pay for de-normalizing)

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=59a418bdae7f52b7c65f7f2c45cdc676)